# Create a scaffold with custom namespace and existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

I want to generate scaffold with a custom namespace but I want it to use an existing model/table.

If I generate a scaffold like this it generate scaffold with a custom namespace but use a new table `admin_locations` :

```
rails generate scaffold Admin::Location
```

Is there a way to do the same thing but using the existing `Location` model and `locations` table ?

Comment: That is not really the purpose of scaffolding you could just generate the controllers and the views though `rails g controller Admin::Locations new create edit index destroy` You will have to add the appropriate routes though.

Comment: @engineersmnky I was looking for a lazy-way to create the views, but I guess I could this and just copy paste the views from a blank CRUD project

Comment: They won't have content, only the default notice `<h1>Admin::Locations#index</h1>....`

Comment: Very true but scaffolded views are extremely simplistic with the intention of them being modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @engineersmnky the best way to do this is :

```
rails g controller Admin::Locations new create edit index destroy
```

Then I suggest to create a blank rails project and do :

```
rails g scaffold Admin::Location
```

After this you can replace views by the ones generated on the newly created app (`/app/views/admin/locations`)

Maybe there is a better solution, I would love to know if it's the case !

Comment: The Rails way to do this is with `rails g scaffold_controller Admin::Locations --model-name=Location`